# How to get the `HREF` values only when `<legend>tax</legend>?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, selenium-webdriver

```
<fieldset class="attachmentTable large"><legend>SMF</legend>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr>
<td>

<a href="

/aems/file/test.html">

</a>
</td>
<td>

foo     

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="attachmentTable large"><legend>tax</legend>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr>
<td>

<a href="

/relf/file/test.html">

</a>
</td>
<td>

foo     

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

I have an html source from a webpage,part of which are given above.Now I want to get the `HREF` values only when `<legend>tax</legend>`? So could you guys help me here for the same?

Comment: So your language is ruby?

Comment: yes, ruby1.9.3 i am using in windows-xp

Comment: Have you tried using an html parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)?

Comment: It looks like `mechanize` depends on `Nokogiri`.

Comment: You are right! i am also feeling the same.

Comment: Your HTML sample is a mess. Please correct it. You're asking people to do extra work just to help you by making them wade through that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
page.search('legend[text()="tax"] + table a').each do |a|
  puts a[:href]
end
```

Comment: How I make a `machanze` agent to `nokogiri`? AS your code using `nokogiri`? what `table a` stands for?

Comment: page can be a mechanize page or a nokogiri document. `+ table a` means the table immediately follows the legend and the a descends from the table.